# Razor string.Format concatenate HTML not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When using this code:

```
<span>@string.Format("{0}{1}",
    true ? "ABC " : string.Empty,
    true ? "<a href=\"https://example.org\">link</a>" : string.Empty)
</span>
```

The output is

`ABC <a href="https://example.org">link</a>`

but I'm trying to achieve

> ABC [link](https://example.org)

https://dotnetfiddle.net/fAAxIh

Comment: Your need to use `@Html.Raw(...)` - see [updated fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FjP1ex)

Comment: `@Html.Raw()` must be used to render HTML tags from server - see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/439sb1).

Comment: Html.Raw did it!